# Mongodb Aggregated documents into a nested hierarchy

Tags: mongodb, recursion, aggregate, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to aggregate documents in a collection to a nested graph. Below is the sample data from comments store application I am working with -

Posts Collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "1", 
    "text" : "hey", 
}
{ 
    "_id" : "2", 
    "text" : "hello", 
    "replyTo" : "1"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "3", 
    "text" : "What's up?", 
    "replyTo" : "2"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "4", 
    "text" : "How are you", 
    "replyTo" : "1"
}

{ 
    "_id" : "5", 
    "text" : "Knock, knock!", 
}
```

The result I am expecting should look like :

```
{
   "_id": "1",
   "text": "hey",
   "replies": [
      {
         "_id": "2",
         "text": "hello",
         "replyTo": "1",
         "replies": [
            {
               "_id": "3",
               "text": "What's up?",
               "replyTo": "2"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "_id": "4",
         "text": "How are you",
         "replyTo": "1"
      }
   ]
}

{ 
    "_id" : "5", 
    "text" : "Knock, knock!", 
}
```

I tried $graphLookup which is processing documents recursively but the results is a flat array which is not what I expect -

```
db.posts.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$graphLookup" : {
                "from" : "posts", 
                "startWith" : "$_id", 
                "connectFromField" : "_id", 
                "connectToField" : "replyTo", 
                "as" : "replies"
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

Result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "1", 
    "text" : "hey", 
    "slug_path" : "1", 
    "replies" : [
        {
            "_id" : "2", 
            "text" : "hello", 
            "slug_path" : "1/2", 
            "replyTo" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "4", 
            "text" : "How are you", 
            "slug_path" : "1/4", 
            "replyTo" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "3", 
            "text" : "what's up?", 
            "slug_path" : "1/2/3", 
            "replyTo" : "2"
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "2", 
    "text" : "hello", 
    "slug_path" : "1/2", 
    "replyTo" : "1", 
    "replies" : [
        {
            "_id" : "3", 
            "text" : "what's up?", 
            "slug_path" : "1/2/3", 
            "replyTo" : "2"
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "4", 
    "text" : "How are you", 
    "slug_path" : "1/4", 
    "replyTo" : "1", 
    "replies" : [

    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "3", 
    "text" : "what's up?", 
    "slug_path" : "1/2/3", 
    "replyTo" : "2", 
    "replies" : [

    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "5", 
    "text" : "Knock, knock!", 
    "replies" : [

    ]`
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve the type of aggregation I am expecting?

Thanks 
Davinder

Comment: Not like that. The `$graphLookup` can indicate which "depth" the match was made at, which you can use in post processing to make your "tree".  From a  data processing, such a structure is really an "anti-pattern", which is a good reason why the output does not produce this way.

Comment: As I thought, Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up ditching $graphLookup as it can only give 1-level parent-child relationships and can't recursively create a tree like structure as results. I was able to create tree like structure completely in Java and program is running fast from performance perspective.